# Mod-Rewrite in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to implement *301 redirection* from `http://www.onbip.com/index-en.html` to `http://www.onbip.com/`

In htaccess file I have:

- RewriteRule `^.htaccess$ - [F,L] #403 Forbidden`
- RewriteRule `^inc/ - [F,L]`
- RewriteCond `%{HTTP_HOST} ^onbip\.com`
- RewriteRule `^(.*)$ http: //www.onbip.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]`
- RewriteRule `^index-([^\.]+)\.html$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]`

I Need to standardize the default page which will be `http://www.onbip.com/`

How?

Comment: Did the answer work for you or do you need more help? If you click answered (if you don't need more help) then people will know that no more input is needed.

Answer (score 1):

In your httpd.conf file, there should already be a line to forbid access to .ht* files that will probably look like this:

```
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>
```

If you want to be redundent, using Files or FilesMatch to protect it would probably be good. If you want to use Rewrite for this, you could throw a 404 as though it doesn't exist.

Here is a redirect (not a mod_rewrite) for a directory /inc to a 404 page

This is at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html

```
Redirect 404 /inc
```

Now for rewrite

see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

```
#Set the page (and order of if they are there) to be shown if asked for a directory
#just put index.php if that's all you want
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

RewriteEngine on

# if not www.onbip.com, then send to http://www.onbip.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.onbip\.com [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://www.onbip.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

# Now if entered "/index-ab.html" then call "/?lang=ab"
# You might want to see about the regex for proper lang, I put something like "en" or "us-en"
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index-([a-z]{2}(-[a-z]{2})?)\.html$ ?lang=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

The last will call "/" from the server which will be "index.php" first if it exists according to directory index.